# Salesforce CPQ - Force users to enter a quantity

Tags: quote, cpq, quotelineitem

I would like to force users to enter a quantity for every line item in the quote line editor.

When saving the quote, Salesforce CPQ will automatically set the quantity to 1 if any value smaller then 1 or a non numeric value is entered in the quantity.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by creating a custom quantity field and a price rule that will copy the quantity of this custom field to the standard quantity field.
Then created a validation rule that won't allow the record to be saved if the custom quantity field is empty or if the quantities from these two fields are not the same.